# pthreads/ wait(&status)

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I read a book that gives the next example:

```
int value=0
int thread_func(int id) {
   int temp;
   temp=value+id;
   printf("Thread%d value: %d", id, temp);
   value=temp;
}

int main() {
   int fork_id, status, i;
   pthread_t tids[3];
   fork_id=fork();
 if (fork_id == 0) {
   for (i=1; i≤3; i++) 
        pthread_create(&tids[i-1], NULL, thread_func, i);
      for (i=0; i≤2; i++)
        pthread_join(tids+i, &status);
      printf("Second process value: %d", value);
  }
 else {
  wait(&status);
      printf("First process value: %d", value)
      }
```

I don't understand two main things:
As I read, the only value that the line has in `printf("First process value: %d", value)` is 0.
But why? wait(&status) is wait until the child process is terminate. In out case, it will terminate only after all the joins would done. meaning, when the value is 6.

Second, in the line `printf("Second process value: %d", value);`, the vaule can be from 1 to 6. This is also strange, because we have the join instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers to your questions:

1. The value will be 0 in the parent process because when the `fork` occurs the address space of the parent is duplicated (along with the variable `value`) in the child process. Hence, although `value` is changed in the child, this change is not reflected in the parent as they are different variables.
2. Since there is no synchronization involved, there is no way to know in which order the variable `value` is changed by the three child threads. Specifically, each thread has a local `temp` variable with a different value, which is then copied in the global `value` variable, but there is no way to know in which order the threads will overwrite `value` with `temp` here: `value = temp;`. Hence, its value can vary between executions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. About my second question: we really can't know  in which order the variable value is changed by the three child threads, BUT we can know that we will arrive to this line after the all three thread were finished (because the join instruction). What I missed?

Comment: @Adam Sh: The problem is that for example in one execution the first thread makes `temp = 0 + 1` and then sets `value = 1`. Then the second thread arrives, makes `temp = 1 + 2` then sets `value = 3` and finally the last thread makes `temp = 3 + 3` and sets `value = 6`. In another possible execution, the first thread sets `temp = 0 + 1`, but before reaching `temp = value` the second thread makes `temp = 0 + 2` (since thread 1 didn't reach `temp = value`) and then makes `value = 2`. Now you can see that the final value will be completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you fork, you get a brand new process with its own memory, which means that changes to a variable in one process won't show up in another. Threads, on the other hand, share their memory, which means that changes to variables in a threaded program show up in all threads.

Answer (score 0):

The value is incremented by the child process, so the parent process will show its value as 0.

```
if(fork_id == 0){
......
......
}
```

is executed by the child which spawned threads.

And child process has different copy of memory. so increasing value in child does not mean the same for parent.

And threads have access to global values.